# Getting viewbag dynamic property's value as null

Tags: c#, view, asp.net-mvc-5, controllers

I am storing a value in dynamic property called login in my Login action method in my controller and I am accessing the value of the viewbag in Index view. I am gettng the value as null. Why is this so.?

Following is my code which is in controllers Login action method.

```
ViewBag.Login = "false";
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

here is my code which I am using in the Index view(cshtml).

```
@if (@ViewBag.Login != "")
```

Here in view I am getting `@ViewBag.Login`'s value as null. Even if i remove the @ symbol like this

```
ViewBag.Login  Still I get value as null.
```

Please help. ViewBag should persist value within view's and action methods which are bind to same controller.

Comment: `ViewBag` is for passing a value from the controller to the view. But you are redirecting and the value is lost. You could assign the value to `TempData`, retrieve it in the `Index()` method and then assign it to `ViewBag`.

Comment: Or just `return View()` instead of redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewBag` does not persist across http requests.

You could do

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
   /* Pass `Login` by QueryString */
   return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Login = false });
}

public ActionResult Index(bool Login) 
{
   /* Read from QueryString, and pass the value to `ViewBag` */
   ViewBag.Login = Login;
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Or, in the first example, store Login in the TempData instead of ViewBag.

Answer (score 1):

The `ViewBag` won't survive across a `RedirectToAction`. You can use `TempData`, which can be accessed exactly once:

```
TempData["Login"] = "false";
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```